# Getting the numeric value from a currency string in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, currency

I'm trying to extract the numeric value from a string as I need to use it in a calculation for totals.

I read in other threads that I should use the PHP **NumberFormatter** function.

Here's my code...

**PHP**

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'za_ZA', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$num = "R1,500.00 ZAR";
var_dump($fmt->parseCurrency($num, $curr));
```

...and the corresponding output I get.

**HTML**

```
<pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr"><small>boolean</small> <font color="#75507b">false</font>
</pre>
```

I have also tried Regular Expression, but it ends up giving me 1 instead of 1500.

I'm not sure where the mistake is and which method I should use.

Comment: You can use `((\d+,)+\d+\.\d+)`. Check [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ1aX4/1)

Comment: You might want to check the formatting -- most South Africans I know would use the comma as a decimal separator rather than a thousands separator.

Comment: What is the value of $curr?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo From what I gather in the documentation, $curr would be the value of the currency. In this case Rand which it gets from 'za_ZA'

Comment: Nope. $curr should be "3-letter ISO 4217 currency code", so for sure not 'za_ZA', but 'ZAR'

Comment: I updated my answer, it's working correctly with the format described there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want just the number and don't care about the currency itself, this will work for you:

```
$num = "R1,500.00 ZAR";
$value = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]+/', '', $num));
var_dump($value); //float(1500)
```

If you want to use **NumberFormatter**, which should be better at handling commas instead of periods and other localisation specific differences, you need to make sure that the string is in correct format. The way you're calling the **parseCurrency** is ok (just make sure you set **$curr** to **ZAR**), yet you get **false** as a result, which means the string format is incorrect.

You can check the format by calling **formatCurrency** on a number. You will see that the correct format is **ZAR1,500.00**, not **R1,500.00 ZAR**.

Small example:

```
<?
  $fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'za_ZA', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
  $curr = 'ZAR';
  $string = $fmt->formatCurrency(1500,$curr);
  var_dump($string); //displays "ZAR1,500.00
  $value = $fmt->parseCurrency($num, $curr);
  var_dump($value); //displays 1500
```

Comment: Great. That did the trick. I was hoping to get the **Number Formatter** working as this is the preferred method but even removing the ZAR didn't seem to help.